# What are all the ways to deal damage on a miss with a Strike action?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

There are several Feats, class abilities, and other mechanics that allow a miss with a Strike action to still deal some damage.

After having this come up in two sessions in a row in dramatic, day-saving fashion (The first time via a Thaumaturge Weapon Implement Adept's Empowerment, the second via the Swashbuckler's Confident Finisher ability), I find myself wondering what other class mechanics, feats, or abilities confer the ability to do some damage on a miss.

Comment: Just to make sure we confine the results, you're specifically looking for features and options that cause Strikes with Failure effects that cause damage (no spell attacks, no adding a Save component vs bonus damage, no non-damage penalties)?

Comment: Yeah, specifically looking for Strikes.

Answer (score 8):

### Fighter

- [Advantageous Assault](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=379) [press] - **Failure** You deal damage to the target equal to the number of weapon damage dice, or that number + 2 if you're wielding the weapon in two hands.
- [Certain Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=397) [press] - **Failure** Your attack deals any damage it would have dealt on a hit, excluding all damage dice. (This removes damage dice from weapon runes, spells, and special abilities, in addition to weapon damage dice.)
- [Brutal Finish](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=406) [press] - **Failure** You deal damage equal to one weapon damage die of the required weapon. Increase this to two dice if you’re at least 18th level.

### Gunslinger

- [Flesh Wound](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3192) - **Failure** Though your attack misses, it still deals one die of damage plus any damage from your weapon specialization class feature. This uses your weapon's normal damage die and damage type. This attack doesn't add extra damage from any other sources or abilities.

### Thaumaturge

- Weapon Implement (Adept 7th) - When you use Implement's Interruption and fail (but don't critically fail) the Strike, you deal 1 damage of the weapon's normal type, possibly applying any bonus damage due to the target's weakness.

### Swashbuckler

- Confident Finisher (1st) - **Failure** You deal half your precise strike damage to the target. This damage type is that of the weapon or unarmed attack you used for the Strike.

  - [Precise Finisher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1536) - Even when your foe avoids your Confident Finisher, you can still hit a vital spot. On a failure with Confident Finisher, you apply your full precise strike damage instead of half.
- Eternal Confidence (19th) - When you Strike as part of a finisher or Opportune Riposte, you can give the Strike the failure effect from the Confident Finisher action, including the increase from Precise Finisher if you have that feat.

Answer (score 4):

Any weapon that deals Splash damage will cause some damage on a Fail (but not a Crit fail). Of course, Splash weapons also deal damage to those around the target on a hit. The amount varies from 1 up, depending on the level of the bomb, and the Alchemist class has feats to increase or vary that.

[Splash Weapons](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=150)