# How can I deal damage on a miss with a Strike as a Thaumaturge?

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e

Thaumaturges can [use or cause weaknesses](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=1227) on enemies, but only against their own Strikes. Therefore it would be very beneficial to deal damage on a miss, any tiny amount can trigger the weakness.

The obvious thing is bombs with the [Splash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=704) trait. **What else can be used before level 9?**

### These do not work

- [Confident Finisher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=550) cannot be used by anyone but a full Swashbuckler, so the Archetype does not help

### These work too late

- [Certain Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=397) is unfortunately has the Press trait, so it quite likely to critically miss. Even worse, you cannot get it before level 20

Comment: After posting my answer, I found this related question: [What are all the ways to deal damage on a miss with a Strike action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203704/47185)

Comment: Added "as a Thaumaturge" to the title question to differentiate it from the other question. Feel free to roll back or re-edit if you don't feel that was warranted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Elemental Ammunition

For 3 gp and an action, [elemental ammunition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1897) lets you add splash damage to most ranged weapons:

> The ammunition deals 1 persistent damage and 1 splash damage.

However, using bombs is more action-efficient if you can fit in [Duelist Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1956) for Quick Draw.

Answer (score 5):

For your Thaumaturge, the most obvious solution, that was designed for exactly this situation, is the Adept benefit of the Weapon Implement, attainable at 7th level.

> Weapon Implement (Adept 7th) - When you use Implement's Interruption and fail (but don't critically fail) the Strike, you deal 1 damage of the weapon's normal type, possibly applying any bonus damage due to the target's weakness.

The only other available to the Thaumaturge are fighter feats with the Press trait. (Though you don’t need to wait for Certain Strike, Advantageous Assault will do).

Comment: Advantageous Assault is available on level 12,and hard to set up. The Weapon Implement's Adept power is probably even harder

Comment: Sure, it’s level 12. That’s better than the level 20 example cited by OP. And the Weapon adept power isn’t hard to set up at all - Implement’s interruption is basically a better attack of opportunity as is. I find it’s usable in most rounds of combat unless the enemies (and players) are specifically both using bad triple strike type tactics.

Comment: Most things you can do in combat beside Stride and spellcasting does not provoke. Spellcasters are rare, and there is usually no reason to Stride

Comment: If there is no reason to stride, your group is not doing sufficient tactical work to set it up. In a group with multiple offensive reactions (which, by level 7, is many, if not most groups), creating opportunities for reaction based attacks is one of the most important elements of group tactics in PF2E. And there are plenty of good ways to do that.

Comment: Very hard to do in PFS, where you do not know the other players/characters. Reactive Strike competes with other reactions. Grabbers cannot move away. More enemies than allies have decent ranged attacks. _There are many reasons why constantly moving away is not the best tactic_